# SSRS - Lookup set to ignore the " " values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder3.0

I have created a lookupset below:

=RTRIM(LTRIM(Join(LookupSet(Fields!Fund_Family.Value & Fields!Portfolio_Company_Name.Value,Fields!Fund_Family.Value & Fields!Portfolio_Company_Name.Value,Fields!Security_Type.Value, "DataSet1")," / ").Remove(1,1)))

This seems to work. However, in some particular cases I have two rows, one with the value the other without the value ("") or the Security Column. However, by doing this join the results look like /Security1. However, it should be Security1.There are also scenarios where it picks up Security 1 / / Security 2.  It should ignore the " " values.

How can I add in this expression. I know there is an expression for ISNothing, but can this be added here?

Answer (score 1):

**Solve it in SQL**

If this was my project I would rather solve this in the SQL query that produces the data.  Since I can't see your SQL query, and it is possible in some circumstances that you can't change the query, I have provided my hacky post-SQL solution.

**Hacky Solution**

For simplicity, I'm going to use `DATA_SET_STRING` to represent your code: `RTRIM(LTRIM(Join(LookupSet(Fields!Fund_Family.Value & Fields!Portfolio_Company_Name.Value,Fields!Fund_Family.Value & Fields!Portfolio_Company_Name.Value,Fields!Security_Type.Value, "DataSet1")`

Something like this will remove empty string names from the list: `=REPLACE(DATA_SET_STRING," / "), "/ /", "/").Remove(1,1)))`

**Empty String & Blank Spaces**

If you want to remove blank space names (" ") as well as empty string ("") then I would first convert blank space names to appear just like empty string, then remove the empty strings.  Nesting `REPLACE` statements can accomplish this:

```
=REPLACE(REPLACE(DATA_SET_STRING," / "), "   ", "  "), "/ /", "/").Remove(1,1)))
```

**Multiple Blanks in a Row**

The biggest limitation to this (other than being impossibly difficult to read and maintain) is that it will only remove a finite number of blank names in a row.  For instance if you have three blank names in a row your original function `DATA_SET_STRING` will return "name 1 / / / / name 2".  My additional `REPLACE` functions will result in a final string of "name 1 / / name 2".  In order to handle multiple blanks in a row you would have to nest more `REPLACE` functions.

Something like this:

```
=REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(DATA_SET_STRING," / "), "   ", "  "), "/ /", "/"), "/ /", "/").Remove(1,1)))
```

Although you can solve specific scenarios with this `REPLACE` approach, it will always be vulnerable to more blanks in a row than you anticipated.

**Warnings**

Again, I would rather solve this problem by providing a query that filters out the blank and empty string names.  However, if you are going to use a hacky approach (I know hacky code can get you out of a jam), here are the weaknesses of the provided solution:

- Hard to read
- Hard to maintain
- Vulnerable to changes in data (too many empty strings in a row)

Remember to code responsibly.